# Using Alsa, How can I get the current levels of audio playing through ffmpeg or mpg123 to display on a web dashboard?

Tags: php, alsa, ffmpeg

I have an app that I built that simply plays an icecast feed from the internet and if the feed is gone, it plays a backup feed or some local audio files. I need a way to show a representation of the playing audio on a dashboard that runs on a nginx server on the same machine. I would like it to be realtime if possible but just showing audio moving is good enough. Also I would use this to do some scripting in case the audio is silent from the stream.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest (though definitely not cheapest, CPU-wise) way to do this that I can come up with is to have ffmpeg output an image with a loudness meter every once in a while, in addition to its normal output. You can do this something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i «INPUT» \
    -filter_complex '[0:a]ebur128=video=1:meter=18:metadata=0[g][j], [j]anullsink, [g]fps=1[g]' \
    -map '[g]' -f image2 -update 1 -y «IMAGEFILE».png \
    -map '0:a' -c:a copy -y «AUDIO_OUTPUT»
```

That should output an image once per second (though note that's per second of processed audio; ffmpeg will as typical run as fast as the CPU allows, at least if the output will accept data that fast. I'm presuming your output limits it to running at 1x). You can change how often the image updates by changing the `fps=` value; 2 would mean twice per second and 0.5 would mean every 2s.

Obviously, if ffmpeg exits, the image will just stop being updated. Similarly if it is stopped e.g., because the output will not take more data, or if the input has none. The modification time on the image will make it obvious enough this has happened. You could also have ffmpeg put a timestamp on top of the image with the current time using the `drawtext` filter:

```
⋮
    -filter_complex '[0:a]ebur128=video=1:meter=18:metadata=0[g][j], [j]anullsink, [g]fps=1, drawtext=text=%{localtime} %{pts}:x=60:y=460:fontcolor=Cyan[g]'
⋮
```

Then you don't even need PHP — you just need to serve a static image:

[image: ffmpeg ebur128 output image showing fairly loud, minimal dynamic range audio playing]

PS: As for scripting if its silent, that'd really be best done in your app — and FYI you can have the same ebur128 filter output metadata in various formats (e.g., JSON) so you can check if its gone silent. Unfortunately it gets mixed in with other ffmpeg output, so parsing can be a bit annoying. I've written [Perl code to do it](https://gitlab.com/derobert/Podist/blob/master/lib/Podist/Processor.pm#L368), but you'll probably find it easy enough to do in the scripting language of your choice.

Comment: This is a cool example of something I didnt realize could be done. I think what I really need is just a file with the audio levels that I can parse with js to animate a little bar. Seems like it would be less weight too. Thoughts?

Comment: @ahackney The CPU there is mostly running EBU R.128, but note the "PS" bit — it'll happily give you JSON output as well or instead of the video. (Indeed, the default is not to give the video; had to turn it on with the "video" option to the filter). To be clear, it's not *that* expensive, but you'd maybe notice it on an embedded system, or if you're doing a lot of streams (since your output is also, I'm guessing you're not). [Of course, if you up the FPS, the PNG encode starts eating a lot of CPU].

Comment: I'm using this in a single board computer project I'm building that sends audio in realtime from one point to another. Can I somehow take the json feed and use it in real time by receiving it on the client side and animating some sort of audio representation? How would I do that?

Comment: I don't really care about the history of the audio levels other than maybe later generating a graph to see when audio played or if I record it, but if I record it, I can generate that a different way. All I'm after is taking the real time audio thats playing through the audio output and grabing the current volume then animating a bar or something to show how the levels are currently.

Comment: @ahackney the astats filter (if I'm remembering the name right, writing this from a phone) will give you audio levels as stream metadata which you can then print out, that might be lower CPU. Anyway, you'd have your app write it to a file somewhere (which PHP could read), offer it over a socket (which PHP could connect to), send it via MQTT (I'm sure PHP has a way to handle), etc. You could even, I guess, send the ffmpeg stdout & stderr to anyone who cares to listen (via UDP) using netcat.

Comment: @ahackney (also, just to be clear, all these files — whether the png or the json — can be on a tmpfs, you don't have to burn flash write cycles on them)

Comment: That's a great idea. I did get it to work with the filter to work. The actual command is this: ffplay -reorder_queue_size 0 -nostats -i stream.sdp -protocol_whitelist "file,http,https,tcp,tls,udp,rtp" -nodisp -af astats=metadata=1:reset=1,ametadata=print:key=lavfi.astats.Overall.RMS_level &> volume.log & Works great. Didnt think about writing it to a tmpfs. This is pretty much exactly what I wanted. Thank you. Accepting your answer. If you want to modify it to show both ways would probably be helpful in the future. Thanks!